# Statistical significance in python

Tags: python, statistics

I have 3 methods to be compared. For each method, I run an experiment 5 times (with different train/test datasets) and I get 5 accuracy values.

I havve then a 3 lists: method1, method2, method3. Each list contains 5 values.

How can I compute in python, if the results for one method (say method1) are significantly different from the two other methods ? This is done by computing the p-value, but I wonder if there is a library allows to easily do that in Python ?

Comment: Is this a Python or a statistics question?

Comment: You should probably take your statistics question over to http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic and when you have a clear framework bring come back to Stack Overflow to ask specific questions about implementing it in Python.

Comment: @timgeb it is a programming question: basically how can I compute the statistical significance (pvalue) from two different lists each list contains 5 values.

Comment: scipy and statsmodels are high-quality libraries supporting a lot of statisticial tests.